# Error when decoding a JSON data from "aqicn.org"

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm a newbie in swift programming and I got stuck into the problem, parsing JSON data which I got from "https://aqicn.org/api/".

Since, the data I want is just an 'aqi', so I made a super simple model below to parse JSON data.
(also please refer to the attached screenshot below)

```
struct Dust: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let aqi: Int
}
```

Also, this is the error message I got.

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "aqi", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"aqi\", intValue: nil) (\"aqi\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

It seems like the model I made is wrong but, I'm not sure what the problem is.
I did changed aqi into String and tried again, but the error still shows up.

Here's decoding function just in case...

```
func parseDustJSON(_ dustData: Data) -> Int? {
        print(#function)
        do {
            let decodedDustData = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataClass.self, from: dustData)
            let dustData = decodedDustData
            return dustData.aqi
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

It would be really appreciate if someone could help me out.

[screenshot of the JSON data I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGO9f.png)

Comment: Put “print(String(data: dustData, encoding:.utf8))”  right above “ let decodedDustData” you’ll be able to see what you are actually receiving

Comment: @loremipsum Hello, I added the printing code u gave, and got "{"status":"error","data":"Unknown station"}" message

Comment: You need to check the API documentation and make sure you submit the correct data in the request. My guess is the station data is incorrect or missing

Comment: @loremipsum the parameter they request is just API token and City...  I made a return code on the URLsession.dataTask if the structed url has error, so I think parsing cannot start if the request is wrong

Comment: The API says “Unknown station” since it is an error “let data: String” with the message. To get what you expect you need to correct the request.

Comment: @HangarRash the whole thing was a typo and the question was not an MRE and most important lacked the cause/typo, per the op’s comments they had already tried your solution and got a string vs object error. The primary issue was the typo, the typo troubleshooting caused the type issue. That is why I voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `Dust.self`, not `DataClass.self`.

```
let decodedDustData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Dust.self, from: dustData)
return decodedDustData.data.aqi
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried it before.. and it said "typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: Then your problem isn't with the decoding of the JSON. Your problem is that you aren't getting the desired JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just doublechecked my request and the city parameter I wrote was wrong.... hope you have a great day!